# Modal is not getting close please check my code

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am printing Badge information using below code, after print Modal box is not getting closed

```
$("#printCnfWithoutLoginForm").formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        emailAdressWLogin: {
            verbose: false,
            trigger: 'blur',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Email is Required'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,
                    message: 'Please enter valid email address'
                },
                remote: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/wp-content/themes/mesocolumn/eventDetailsAjax.php/',
                    message: 'Sorry, You have not register for this event',
                    data: {
                        eventidWLogin: function () {
                            return $('#eventidWLogin').val()
                        },
                        eventtypeWLogin: function () {
                            return $('#eventtypeWLogin').val()
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(e.target),
                    fv = $form.data('formValidation');
            var data = $form.serialize();
            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
                    var is_chrome = Boolean(printWindow.chrome);
                    printWindow.document.write(data);
                    if (is_chrome) {
                        setTimeout(function () { // wait until all resources loaded 
                            printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                            printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                            printWindow.print(); // change window to winPrint
                            printWindow.close(); // change window to winPrint
                        }, 400);
                    } else {
                        printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                        printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                        printWindow.print();
                        printWindow.close();
                    }
  }
            });
            $('#autoUpdate2').modal('hide');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually called the `remove()` method to close the modal as

```
 $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
 $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: This code works fine, but i need to click twice after closing the modal in order to open again

Comment: you can do one thing, call click function in your ajax success 

$('yourID').click();

Comment: Wow , it works fine for me Thanks for the help .. But still i am confuse , why its possible with your code, but not with this code 
$('#autoUpdate2').modal('hide');

Comment: Google it you will get more ideas about Modal ... God bless you ;)